# SUMIF function criteria is currency

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[image: See the question below.]

In the image are two tables. The one in column A has a list of currencies. The table in columns C-E has products and their price.

I would like to sum D2:D6 if the currency in the range E2:E6 is equal to A2. This is a simple sumif function that usually works for me, for some reason it won't work with currency.

The function I tried is in G3:
SUMIF(D2:D6,E2:E6,A2)

D2:D6- sum range,
E2:E6- criteria range,
A2- criteria

I also tried changing the currency from the symbol to the abbreviation (USD instead of $ sign), but that also didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me in Excel 2016

[image]

Make sure you don't have any leading or trailing spaces next to the currency symbols in each of your tables. Sometimes when data is copied and pasted from other sources, some rogue symbols like character 160 (web character for a space) will travel with the pasted values and can cause this kind of result.

For the record: it works with currency names instead of symbols, too.

[image]

Comment: @dshaviv The difference between yours and telylyn's answer is you used SUMIF() and the answer uses SUMIFS(), so try it.